# Converting python requests to aiohttp and adding error handling to it

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

This code was my synchronous code using the Python requests library:

```
    def request_with_error_handling(self, item_id):
        browse_url = f'https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item/v1|{item_id}|0'
        while True:
            try:
                rq = requests.get(browse_url, headers=self.browse_headers)
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'An error has occurred while processing the request: {str(e)}')
                t.sleep(1)

        return rq
```

If I get an error while making the connection I wait for a second and try again, but if all goes well, then I break out of the loop and return the respose.

However, when I try to do that with aiohttp:

```
    async def request_with_error_handling(self, browse_url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            while True:
                try:
                    async with session.get(browse_url, headers=self.browse_headers) as response:
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    print(
                        f'An error has occurred while processing the request: {str(e)}')
                    t.sleep(1)

        return response
```

my IDE gives me a red zigzag line and tells me the following:

> The break statement
> break_stmt ::=  "break"
> break may only occur syntactically nested in a for or while loop, but not nested in a function or class definition within that loop.
> It terminates the nearest enclosing loop, skipping the optional else clause if the loop has one.
> If a for loop is terminated by break, the loop control target keeps its current value.
> When break passes control out of a try statement with a finally clause, that finally clause is executed before really leaving the loop.

How can I convert the same logic that I had with requests into aiohttp code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your indentation reflects the fact that you are reproducing a method within a class. Anyway, you need to further indent your `break`:

```py
    async def request_with_error_handling(self, browse_url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            while True:
                try:
                    async with session.get(browse_url, headers=self.browse_headers) as response:
                        break
                except Exception as e:
                    print(
                        f'An error has occurred while processing the request: {str(e)}')
                    t.sleep(1)

        return response
```